# What's the benefits of `mid = low + (high -low)//2` over `(low + high)//2`?

Tags: python

I am working on a Tree problem [Convert Sorted Array to Binary Search Tree - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/convert-sorted-array-to-binary-search-tree/)

> Given an array where elements are sorted in ascending order, convert it to a height balanced BST.
>
> For this problem, a height-balanced binary tree is defined as a binary tree in which the depth of the two subtrees of *every* node never differ by more than 1.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```py
> Given the sorted array: [-10,-3,0,5,9],
>
> One possible answer is: [0,-3,9,-10,null,5], which represents the following height balanced BST:
>
>       0
>      / \
>    -3   9
>    /   /
>  -10  5
> ```

An intuitive D&Q solution is

```
class Solution:
    def sortedArrayToBST(self, nums: List[int]) -> TreeNode:
        """
        Runtime: 64 ms, faster than 84.45%
        Memory Usage: 15.5 MB, less than 5.70% 
        """
        if len(nums) == 0: return None
        #if len(nums) == 1: return TreeNode(nums[0])
        mid = len(nums) // 2
        root = TreeNode(nums[mid])
        if len(nums) == 1: return root 
        if len(nums) > 1: 
            root.left = self.sortedArrayToBST(nums[:mid])
            root.right = self.sortedArrayToBST(nums[mid+1:])
        return root
```

`mid` is set as `len(nums)//2` or `(low + high)//2`

When read other submissions, I found

```
class Solution:
    def sortedArrayToBST(self, nums: List[int]) -> TreeNode:
        return self.buildBST(nums, 0, len(nums))

    def buildBST(self, nums, left, right):
        if right <= left:
            return None
        if right == left + 1:
            return TreeNode(nums[left])

        mid = left + (right - left) // 2
        root = TreeNode(nums[mid])
        root.left = self.buildBST(nums, left, mid)
        root.right = self.buildBST(nums, mid + 1, right)

        return root
```

`mid` was set as `mid = low + (high -low)//2`

What's the benefits of `mid = low + (high -low)//2` over `(low + high)//2`?

Comment: My guess is that it was ported from a language with fixed-size integers, where that approach avoids integer overflow when you have really big arrays. In Python, you don’t have to worry about that.

Comment: Could you please transmit the comment to answer @Ry-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s a pattern to avoid integer overflow; the code was probably ported from a language with fixed-size integers. When the indexes can get as big as the types used to contain them, overflow of the intermediate `low + high` value becomes a problem, leading to undefined behaviour, incorrect results, and vulnerabilities. (This even happens with large integer types like `size_t` when you’re [searching something that’s not an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735259/calculating-mid-in-binary-search/6735322#6735322).)

… But in Python, there is no integer overflow, so you’re right that you can just do `(low + high) // 2`.

Answer (score 1):

in many language, such as C++, JAVA. integer has fixed value range, such as:

int32: -2147483648 ~ 2147483647
int64: -9223372036854775808 ~ 9223372036854775807

sometimes low and high in valid range, but `low + high` may overflow.

so it is safer to use difference like `mid = low + (high -low)//2`

but it is not necessary for python, because it works like `BigInteger` in Java.