# Binary search returning wrong answer many times

Tags: java, binary-search

I've implemented the iterative binary search algorithm which returns the index of the found element (-1 if the element isn't in the array):

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] array, int target) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = array.length - 1;

    while (left <= right) {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (array[mid] == target) {
            return mid;
        } else if (array[mid] < target) {
            right = mid - 1;
        } else {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

When I try to test it on an element that is not in the array it returns the correct answer, when I tried it with the array: `{1,5,23,111}` and the target is the number 5 it returned the correct result which is 1 in this case, however when I tried with that same array but the number 111 it returned -1, I've also tried with different arrays and multiple target numbers and many times it returned -1 even though the number is present in the array, any help on why this is happening?

Comment: What happens when you run this in a debugger?

Comment: This condition - `array[mid]<target` - is the wrong way around. It should be: `target < array[mid]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your left/right advancement is backwards.  When the element at the current `mid` position is less than the target, then you need to search the right half, and when the element at the current `mid` position is greater than the target (`else` block), you need to search the left half.

The only reason you found `5` correctly is that `mid` happened to be correct in the first iteration.

Switch your statements in the `else if` and `else` blocks.

```
else if (array[mid] < target) { left = mid + 1; }
else { right = mid - 1; }
```

Or alternatively reverse the sense of comparison for the `else if` condition.

```
else if (array[mid] > target) { right = mid - 1; }
else { left = mid + 1; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some logical problem in your program.

1. The first problem is using `else` with the `if` condition containing a `return` statement. Since the method will `return` when the `if` condition is `true`, putting an `else` is useless. The use of `else` is required to choose either of the two options (i.e. not both of them). After using the `return` statement with the first option, you are already disallowing the second option.
2. The second problem is misplacing the calculation for `right` and `left` variables. **The logic should be:** Ignore the left half if the `target` is greater than the number at `mid`, and to do this, simply advance `left` by one position beyond `mid`; otherwise (i.e. if the `target` is `less` than the number at `mid`), ignore the right half by moving `right` backwards by one position.

Given below is the working program:

```
public class BinarySearchDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 1, 5, 23, 111 };
        System.out.println(binarySearch(arr, 23));
        System.out.println(binarySearch(arr, 20));
    }

    public static int binarySearch(int[] array, int target) {
        int left = 0;
        int right = array.length - 1;

        while (left <= right) {
            int mid = left + (right - 1) / 2;
            if (array[mid] == target) {
                return mid;
            }
            if (array[mid] < target) {
                left = mid + 1;
            } else {
                right = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
-1
```

Comment: Instead of just fixing the issue, you should explain it so the op can learn

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you are updating `left` and `right`. You are updating them in the incorrect if statements.

When `array[mid] < target`, you want to update the `left` pointer and search in the right subarray, and vice versa.

So your updates should look like this:

```
else if (array[mid] < target) { left = mid + 1; } 
else { right = mid - 1; }
```

Answer (score 1):

*Wanted to add as comment, but cannot comment yet*

After you've fixed your code with correct logic (as in answers above), here is something to improve to your code:

Don't do this: `int mid=(left+right)/2;` 
Do this: `int mid = low + ((high - low) / 2);` or this `int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;`

Refer this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735259/calculating-mid-in-binary-search)